# Ecto cast_assoc Pheonix edit form validation

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I am working on Ex_admin setting up the ability to have custom changesets. We are using the new cast_assoc and put_assoc features in Ecto 2. I am curious how people are handling the following scenario as it doesn't seem to be well supported to my knowledge by the Ecto Pheonix form combo:

1. We have a schema with a has many relationship.
2. The user goes to an edit form, edits the data in the parent schema in
   an invalid way.
3. The user deletes a has many relationship.
4. The user submits the invalid form.
5. The changeset with the validation error is used to re-render the edit form so the validation error can be fixed.

In order to remove the relationship using cast_assoc, you actually need to remove the deleted item from the params passed into the cast_assoc method. When the parent schema is valid this works ok. However when the edit form needs to be re-rendered using the invalid changeset the deleted assoc is missing. This is a weird ui experience since the user should see the same state as what they submitted, with the errors added.

So how are people getting the deleted association back into the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems you can do this on the related schema side by attaching a delete action to the nested changeset. It is covered well near the bottom of this article http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/08/working-with-ecto-associations-and-embeds/

Answer (score 0):

I have recently merged a PR that improves the handling of associations. We have removed the "magic" from ex_admin and delegate that responsibility to your changeset. The readme file and tests have several examples.

If you are using `has_many :through` for your many-to-many associations, you should convert them to `:many_to_many`. This can be done without any schema changes.

Please checkout the master branch on GitHub.